# How are bytes counted in bitmap-based esolangs?

Tags: discussion

There are some esolangs like [Brainloller](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainloller).

This is the hello world program for that language:
[image: Hello world]

How are bytes counted here?

Comment: They aren't, they're counted as pixels

Comment: As with all languages, you simply count the size of the source file (in this case the bitmap).